# How do I create a number of variables in a programme WHILE it is running?

Tags: python

I want to create a half life generator game like the ones you learn in high school (you roll like 50 dice and is there is 4 or more on one dice, you don't roll it again). To do this, I want to set up a number of variables to be the dice.
Just one problem: how do I do that in python?
I basically want the programme to generate multiple variables from a user input and then assign a random function to do that.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are probably best off creating a list or a dict, container objects which can contain as many other objects as you need. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html

Comment: Instead of multiple variables, use a list. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists